# What is right way to access elements of std::array by passing as a pointer to function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

The code snippet is as follows. The error is in foo function for the cout line:

```
typedef struct Datatype {
    int first;
    int second;
} Datatype;

void foo(std::array<Datatype, 100>* integerarray){
    cout << *integerarray[0].first << endl; //ERROR: has no member first
}

void main() {
    std::array<Datatype, 100> newarray;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        newarray[i] = i;
    }
    foo(&newarray);
}
```

Comment: Pass by reference instead of by pointer, then this problem does not arise

Comment: (6): error C2039: 'array': is not a member of 'std'
(6): error C2065: 'array': undeclared identifier
(6): error C2275: 'Datatype': illegal use of this type as an expression
(6): error C2065: 'integerarray': undeclared identifier
(6): error C2182: 'foo': illegal use of type 'void'
(6): error C2448: 'foo': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
(10): warning C4326: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'
(11): error C2039: 'array': is not a member of 'std'
(11): error C2065: 'array': undeclared identifier
(11): error C2275: 'Datatype': illegal ...

Comment: Please do not omit `#include` directives when copying your code to the question. Never use `void main`, it is non-standard. `main` should return `int`.

Answer (score 9):

Because of operator precedence, `*integerarray[0].first` is translated as `*(integerarray[0].first)`, which is not what you want. You need to use `(*integerarray)[0].first`.

```
cout << (*integerarray)[0].first << endl;
```

You can make your life simpler by passing a reference.

```
void foo(std::array<Datatype, 100>& integerarray){
  cout << integerarray[0].first << endl;
}
```

Also, you don't need to use `typedef struct DataType { ... } DataType;` in C++. You can use just `struct DataType { ... };`

Answer (score -1):

### newarray[i] = i;

In this line you have missed adding value to structure variables.
Also you have passed array as a reference to function. Removing it and passing just the name of array will pass base address of array.
I am adding following code for your reference:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <array>
struct Datatype{
int first;
int second;
}

typedef Datatype varInts;
void display(std::array<varInts,20> &dummy)
{
int b =5;
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
dummy[i].first =b++;
dummy[i].second = b+5; //Give any logic you wish.just adding different values;
b++;
}
}
int main()
{
std::array<varInts,20> data;
int a =1;
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
 data[i].first = a++;
data[i].second = a+5;
a++; //Just adding values for example
}
display(data);
return 0;
}
```

It runs without error.Hope it helps!!

Comment: This answer bears little relevance to the question, as far as I can tell.

Comment: _"Also you have passed array as a reference to function"_ No, it was a pointer

Comment: _"Removing it and passing just the name of array will pass base address of array"_ No, now you're passing a reference